# Implementing xoai 4.x

Tags: oai

I would like to implement a standalone oai-pmh version 2 data provider server using xoai 4.1.x without DSpace.

Can anyone direct me to any documentation for doing this or to a reference implementation?
Thanks
David

Answer (score 1):

Its posible, but you will need a repository to manage the contents that oai serve.
You should check https://github.com/lyncode/xoai/wiki for help and https://github.com/lyncode/xoai to get the code.